# flask_restx APP with Nginx + Gunicorn in Docker doesn't respond to HTTP-Requests

Tags: docker, nginx, httprequest, gunicorn, flask-restx

My flask_restx application is running in a docker container, with nginx as reverse proxy and Gunicorn workers.

When I send a HTTP-Request to my application, the expected result is a response after the application does its job, which takes about 3-5 minutes.

However, I fail to get a response to my request after about a minute after sending the request.

I added a timeout to my gunicorn config. Before I did that, I received a 502 Bad Gateway error from the nginx-server after 30 seconds, as the default timeout of gunicorn is 30 seconds.

In any case, in the background, my application works as intended and successfully does its job. It is only the response to my request that doesn't work properly.

Furthermore, I was able to see the print messages of my application when I didn't have `--timeout 300` specified for gunicorn, but the workers timed out and booted up randomly during the time my application received a request.

Here is the gunicorn config as defined in the Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 5000
CMD gunicorn --workers 3  --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app --log-level=debug --timeout 300
```

The nginx config:

```
server {
      listen 8080 ssl;
      server_name  localhost;

 access_log  off;
 error_log off;

location / {
  proxy_pass              http://application-url:5000/;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        Host  $host;
  proxy_redirect          off;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_connect_timeout   90001;
  proxy_send_timeout      90001;
  proxy_read_timeout      90001;
  send_timeout 90001;
  client_max_body_size    10m;
  client_body_buffer_size 128k;
  proxy_buffer_size       4k;
  proxy_buffers           4 32k;
  proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
}


}
```

Here is the log of the container:

```
Run pod=$( kubectl get pods -n application | grep application | grep -v nginx | awk '{print $1}')
[2022-08-03 16:23:16 +0000] [7] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
  config: ./gunicorn.conf.py
  wsgi_app: None
  bind: ['0.0.0.0:5000']
  backlog: 2048
  workers: 3
  worker_class: sync
  threads: 1
  worker_connections: 1000
  max_requests: 0
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  timeout: 300
  graceful_timeout: 300
  keepalive: 2
  limit_request_line: 4094
  limit_request_fields: 100
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  reload: False
  reload_engine: auto
  reload_extra_files: []
  spew: False
  check_config: False
  print_config: False
  preload_app: False
  sendfile: None
  reuse_port: False
  chdir: /application/connector/
  daemon: False
  raw_env: []
  pidfile: None
  worker_tmp_dir: None
  *** 101
  group: 0
  umask: 0
  initgroups: False
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  accesslog: None
  disable_redirect_access_to_syslog: False
  access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
  errorlog: -
  loglevel: debug
  capture_output: False
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  logconfig: None
  logconfig_dict: {}
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  syslog: False
  syslog_prefix: None
  syslog_facility: user
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  statsd_host: None
  dogstatsd_tags: 
  statsd_prefix: 
  proc_name: None
  default_proc_name: wsgi:app
  pythonpath: None
  paste: None
  on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x7f2c8dfc8a60>
  on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x7f2c8dfc8b80>
  when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x7f2c8dfc8ca0>
  pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x7f2c8dfc8dc0>
  post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x7f2c8dfc8ee0>
  post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x7f2c8ddb3040>
  worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x7f2c8ddb3160>
  worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x7f2c8ddb3280>
  pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x7f2c8ddb33a0>
  pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x7f2c8ddb34c0>
  post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x7f2c8ddb3550>
  child_exit: <function ChildExit.child_exit at 0x7f2c8ddb3670>
  worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x7f2c8ddb3790>
  nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x7f2c8ddb38b0>
  on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x7f2c8ddb39d0>
  proxy_protocol: False
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  keyfile: None
  certfile: None
  ssl_version: 2
  cert_reqs: 0
  ca_certs: None
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  ciphers: None
  raw_paste_global_conf: []
  strip_header_spaces: False
[2022-08-03 16:23:16 +0000] [7] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-08-03 16:23:16 +0000] [7] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2022-08-03 16:23:16 +0000] [7] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (7)
[2022-08-03 16:23:16 +0000] [7] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-08-03 16:23:16 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[2022-08-03 16:23:16 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
[2022-08-03 16:23:16 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
[2022-08-03 16:23:16 +0000] [7] [DEBUG] 3 workers
[2022-08-03 16:23:34 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] GET /cgi-bin/ExportLogs.sh
[2022-08-03 16:23:39 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] POST /
[2022-08-03 16:23:39 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] GET /downloader.php
[2022-08-03 16:24:04 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] GET /
[2022-08-03 16:24:04 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] GET /swaggerui/droid-sans.css
[2022-08-03 16:25:16 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] Ignoring EPIPE
[2022-08-03 16:25:39 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] PUT /wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/pub/sns.php
[2022-08-03 16:26:01 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] GET /index.php
[2022-08-03 16:26:06 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] GET /listing/
[2022-08-03 16:26:42 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] GET /filter/jmol/js/jsmol/php/jsmol.php
[2022-08-03 16:27:50 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] POST /ViewPoint/admin/Site/ViewPointLogin
[2022-08-03 16:28:07 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] GET /wp-json/wp/v2/asked-question
[2022-08-03 16:28:57 +0000] [11] [DEBUG] GET /client/index.html
[2022-08-03 16:31:11 +0000] [11] [DEBUG] GET /_users/_all_docs
[2022-08-03 16:31:30 +0000] [11] [DEBUG] POST /json-rpc/
[2022-08-03 16:33:15 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] GET /wp-json/anycomment/v1/auth/wordpress
[2022-08-03 16:33:20 +0000] [11] [DEBUG] GET /sell-media-search/
[2022-08-03 16:33:21 +0000] [11] [DEBUG] GET /index.php
[2022-08-03 16:33:55 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] GET /module/smartblog/archive
[2022-08-03 16:34:12 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] GET /.git/config
[2022-08-03 16:34:22 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] GET /docker-compose.yml
[2022-08-03 16:34:26 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] GET /docker-compose.prod.yml
[2022-08-03 16:34:30 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] GET /docker-compose.production.yml
[2022-08-03 16:34:34 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] GET /docker-compose.staging.yml
[2022-08-03 16:34:38 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] GET /docker-compose.dev.yml
[2022-08-03 16:34:42 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] GET /docker-compose-dev.yml
[2022-08-03 16:34:46 +0000] [11] [DEBUG] GET /docker-compose.override.yml
[2022-08-03 16:34:49 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] GET /docker-cloud.yml
[2022-08-03 16:35:47 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] GET /maint/modules/endpointcfg/endpointcfg.php
```